# Determine if an integer is a circular prime

Tags: python, primes

I've been trying to solve project euler problem 35, and need to make a function that will tell me if an integer is a circular prime. I have a standard `isprime` function and a function to give a list of the rotation of the digits. My rotate code and `iscircularprime` code are here:

```
def rotate(n):
    rotlist = []
    m = str(n)
    counter = 0
    while counter < len(str(n)):
        m = m[1:] + m[0]
        rotlist.append(int(m))
        counter += 1
    return rotlist

def iscircularprime(n):
    np = [0,2,4,5,6,8]
    y = str(n)
    for j in y:
        if int(j) in np:
            return False
    if isprime(n)==False:
        return False
    m = rotate(n)
    for i in m:
        if isprime(i)==True:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

I have not included my `isprime` function as it is fairly standard. My function will correctly identify if a prime is circular, as with 197, but will also identify some non-circular primes as circular, such as 191, which is not circular as 119 is not prime.

Answer (score 3):

You `return True` after one rotation, so you don't check all circular primes.  You should change it to:

```
def iscircularprime(n):
    np = [0,2,4,5,6,8]
    y = str(n)
    for j in y:
        if int(j) in np:
            return False
    if isprime(n)==False:
        return False
    m = rotate(n)

    # new code here
    is_circ_prime = True
    for i in m:
        if not isprime(i):
            is_circ_prime = False
    return is_circ_prime
```

Comment: Ah this is useful, should be fine finishing off the problem then, thank for the help

Answer (score 0):

Untested but I think this is how I solved it years ago.

Easiest way is a quick helper:

```
from collections import deque
def shifter(num):
 strnum = deque(str(num))
 for i in xrange(len(strnum)):
     yield int(''.join(strnum))
     strnum.rotate()
```

Then:

```
sum(1 for i in xrange(1000000) if all(is_prime(p) for p in shifter(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function which circulates any number:

```
def circulate_number(A):
  for v in range(len(str(A))):
        a , i , s =  str(A), len(str(A)), ''
        for c in range(i):
              s += str(a[(v+c) % i])
        print(s)
        v+= 1

circulate_number(123456)
```

Answer (score 0):

The obligatory inefficient one-liner solution.  The left side of the statement is the prime checker, the right side is the rotations generator:

```
from math import factorial as f

def is_circular_prime(n):
    return (lambda s: all(f(i - 1) % i == i - 1 for i in (int(s[j:] + s[:j]) for j in range(len(s)))))(str(n))

for number in range(2, 10000):
    if is_circular_prime(number):
        print(number)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
> python3 test.py
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
31
37
71
73
79
97
113
131
197
199
311
337
373
719
733
919
971
991
1193
1931
3119
3779
7793
7937
9311
9377
>
```